# Matlab: Help in implementing quantized time series

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am having trouble implementing this code due to the variable `s_k` being logical 0/1. In what way can I implement this statement?

[image]

`s_k` is a random sequence of `0/1` generated using a `rand()` and quantizing the output of `rand()` by its mean given below. After this, I don't know how to implement. Please help.

```
 N =1000;
    input = randn(N);

    s = (input>=0.5); %converting into logical 0/1;
```

**UPDATE**

```
N = 3;
tmax = 5;
y(1) = 0.1;
for i =1 : tmax+N-1 %// Change here
        y(i+1) = 4*y(i)*(1-y(i));  %nonlinear model for generating the input to Autoregressive model
    end
 s = (y>=0.5);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (0:tmax), (0:N-1).');
x = sum(s(ind+1).*(2.^(-ind+N+1)));  % The output of this conversion should be real numbers

% Autoregressive model of order 1
z(1) =0;
for j =2 : N
    z(j) =  0.195 *z(j-1) + x(j);
end
```

Comment: Well you are using `randn` not `rand`, which is probably not what you intended. Then you have `s_k`, so what is `k`? Once you know `k`, you should be able to work out `2^(-(k-n+1))` etc.

Comment: (Another question in which the code had been deleted, rolled back by another user at the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've generated the random `logical` sequence, which is great.  You also need to know `N`, which is the total number of points to collect at one time, as well as a list of time values `t`.  Because this is a discrete summation, I'm going to assume the values of `t` are discrete.  What you need to do first is generate a sliding window matrix.  Each column of this matrix represents a set of time values for each value of `t` for the output.  This can easily be achieved with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).  Assuming a maximum time of `tmax`, a starting time of `0` and a neighbourhood size `N` (like in your equation), we can do:

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (0:tmax), (0:N-1).');
```

For example, assuming `tmax = 5` and `N = 3`, we get:

```
ind =

     0     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

Each column represents a time that we want to calculate the output at and every row in a column shows a list of time values we want to calculate for the desired output.

Finally, to calculate the output `x`, you simply take your `s_k` vector, make it a column vector, use `ind` to access into it, do a point-by-point multiplication with `2^(-k+N+1)` by substituting `k` with what we got from `ind`, and sum along the rows.  So:

```
s = rand(max(ind(:))+1, 1) >= 0.5;
x = sum(s(ind+1).*(2.^(-ind+N+1)));
```

The first statement generates a random vector that is as long as the maximum time value that we have.  Once we have this, we use `ind` to index into this random vector so that we can generate a sliding window of `logical` values.  We need to offset this by 1 as MATLAB starts indexing at 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code works for a particular case when I use an arbitrary signal instead of using rand(). Could you please have a look at the Question where I have applied your answer for a different case. In this case, instead of using rand() I am using a nonlinear model to generate the input which is then quantized. The error is "index exceeds matrix dimension". Thank you for your prompt reply & effort.

Comment: Where is this non-linear model you speak of?  Please update your question.

Comment: You need to make the `for` loop go up to `tmax + N - 1` to be able to get the end of the buffer for the last point.  Therefore, change your loop to `for i = 1 : tmax+N-1`

Comment: Do you mean the first for loop i ? I need to initialize the first element of the vector z as z(1) = 0.0. as the Autoregressive model starts from the second element onwards.

Comment: Yes first `for` loop `i`.  Also you changed your code when I commented about `z`.  I'll change your code so you can see.